# Magento's Observer event isn't working and using webservices inside a Observer class

Tags: web-services, magento, soap, module, observers

I'm trying to create a dynamic product discount using values from a webservice.

I've searched some guides on the internet about this matter and I found that I needed to use `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and `checkout_cart_update_items_after`.

However, I followed some guides. Created my own module (which is visible in Magento back office: Configuration > Advanced > Modules) and a observer for this module. I didn't create anything more but it's not working. Since I can see the module in that menu, I believe the problem is on the observer/event call.

Here is the config.xml (which is inside app\code\local\namespace\MyModule\etc) for my module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <namespace_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </namespace_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
             <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                   <observers>
                        <namespace_MyModule_Discount>
                           <class>MyModule/Observer</class>
                           <method>MyModulePriceChange</method>
                         </namespace_MyModule_Discount>
                    </observers>
              </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
         </events>
     </global>
</config>
```

And this is my Observer (which is inside app\code\local\namespace\MyModule\Model) for my module:

```
<?php
    class namespace_MyModule_Model_Observer
    {
        public function MyModulePriceChange(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
        {
            // Get the quote item
            $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
            // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one
            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            // Load the custom price
            $price = $this->_getPriceByItem($item);
            // Set the custom price
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            // Enable super mode on the product.
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }

        protected function _getPriceByItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
        {
            $price = 4;

            //use $item to determine your custom price.

            return $price;
        }

    }
?>
```

Also, is it possible do call soap client to use a webservice inside a observer?

I hope my question is clear, thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues with your config.xml. First of all, use capitalized both company name and module name. `namespace_MyModule` will become your namespace.
You have to declare models under global section like this:

```
<models>
    <mycompany_mymodule>
        <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model</class>
    </mycompany_mymodule>
</models>
```

This will tell magento you want to use `mycompany_mymodule` for models in your module, and class name of each module will start with `Mycompany_Mymodule_Model`.
Where Mycompany and Mymodule are respective to folders of your module: app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule.

The `modules` section of config.xml should also have this namespace (`Mycompany_Mymodule`), matching name of your file app/etc/modules and folder structure in app/code/local.

The observers then become the following (I added type, and changed class):

```
<observers>
    <namespace_MyModule_Discount>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>mycompany_mymodule/Observer</class>
        <method>MyModulePriceChange</method>
    </namespace_MyModule_Discount>
</observers>
```

Then try to test your observer method by adding there some code like `die("message")`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the models tag in the config.xml file.
An observer is a model after all and magento will not know where to find it (that MyModule/Observer you reference). Below it's an example of declaring models tag:

```
<models>
   <MyModule>
      <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model</class> 
   </MyModule>
</models>
```

Yes, you can do soap api calls inside observer.